# linq.js join with two json

Tags: join, linq.js

I have two json data

```
var orders = [
   {seller: "Test1", sell_count: 5, sell_amount: 1500},
   {seller: "Test2", sell_count: 2, sell_amount: 7500}
];
var views = [
   {seller: "Test1", pc_view: 123, mobile_view: 87},
   {seller: "Test2", pc_view:56, mobile_view:23},
   {seller: "Test3", pc_view: 13, mobile_view:7}
];
```

using linq.js how to join like below

```
result = [
    {seller: "Test1", view_count : 210, sell_count: 5, sell_amount: 15000},
    {seller: "Test2", view_count : 79, sell_count: 2, sell_amount: 7500},
    {seller: "Test3", view_count : 20, sell_count: 0, sell_amount: 0}
]
```

please help me!

Comment: Seems an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269) to me. Why do you have JSON strings in the first place? What's the source of these strings and can't the desired format be returned by the source of the data?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a builtin way to perform a full outer join so you'll have to replicate it. There's many ways this could be achieved, here's one.

```
var result = Enumerable.From(orders).Concat(views).Select("$.seller").Distinct().OrderBy()
    .Let(ks => {
        var os = Enumerable.From(orders).ToDictionary("$.seller");
        var vs = Enumerable.From(views).ToDictionary("$.seller");
        return ks.Select(k => {
            var o = os.Get(k) || {};
            var v = vs.Get(k) || {};
            return {
                seller: o.seller || v.seller,
                view_count: v.pc_view + v.mobile_view || 0,
                sell_count: o.sell_count || 0,
                sell_amount: o.sell_amount || 0
            };
        });
    });
```